# The parameters of the objects in my list change even if I clone the list

Tags: c#, list

Good morning,

I make a software that creates steps from the above and adds them to a common list.

Here's my code:

```
        List<List<Crêpe>> Solutions = new List<List<Crêpe>>(); 
        Solutions.Add(new List<Crêpe>(Ordre)); // 1.

        for (int i = NombreMax; i > 0; i--)
        {
            Ordre.Reverse(0, positionDuNombreAChercher); // 2.

            for (int n = 0; n < positionDuNombreAChercher; n++)
            {
                Ordre[n].FaceCraméBienPlacé = !Ordre[n].FaceCraméBienPlacé; // 3.
            }

            Solutions.Add(new List<Crêpe>(Ordre)); 

        }
```

I've put some markers to explain my problem to you:

**In 1**, **I clone my list** and add it in "Solution".

**In 2**, **I reverse the "Ordre"** list, **which no longer has a link with the list I cloned** because it is a clone and therefore the changes are not made in "Solution".

**In 3**, you can see **I'm changing the parameters of the object in "Ordre"**. That's where the error happens!
So I change my parameters in the object and my list that I clone **is not supposed to change it's parameter's object because it was cloned but the problem is that the list that I cloned at the beginning to also change these object parameters**.

to note:
She changed her settings but not her order, as step 3 does with this list.

I'm really sorry if that wasn't clear, if you want a better explanation tell me.

Thank you for helping me :)

EDIT :
Here is the object :

```
internal class Crêpe
{
    internal int Nombre { get; set; }
    internal bool FaceCraméBienPlacé { get; set; }

    public Crêpe(int position, bool faceCraméBienPlacé)
    {
        Nombre = position;
        FaceCraméBienPlacé = faceCraméBienPlacé;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where's the code for `Ordre`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You copied the *list*, but you didn't copy the *crêpes*!

To copy the crêpes, you can write a `GetCopy` method in the `Crêpe` class:

```
public Crêpe GetCopy() => new Crêpe(Nombre, FaceCraméBienPlacé);
```

And then use `Select` to create a copy of *each* `Crêpe`, then use `ToList` to create a new list:

```
Solutions.Add(Ordre.Select(x => x.GetCopy()).ToList()); // 1.
```

You should also change the last line in the outer loop.